# nodejs prototype and nested callbacks with mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, nested

I have two problems with the code below. It is the beginning of a node.js module for registering users that are stored in a mysql database.

The first problem is that in the callback from the first query the variable *this.connection* is undefined. The second problem is that the variable *user* is also undefined in the same callback. Hence the code crashes on the following line:

```
this.connection.query('INSERT INTO users{{values values}}', {
                    values: {
                        user_name: user.username,
                        user_email: user.email,
                        user_password: user.password
                    }
                })
```

Please let me know how to solve this in a propper way.

Many thanks!

Full code is below:

```
module.exports = usermodel;

//connection is a mysql-wrapper connection
function usermodel(connection)
{
    this.connection = connection;
}

playermodel.prototype = {

    registerByEmail: function (user, callback) {
        //check firts if the user already exists
        this.connection.query('SELECT user_id FROM users {{where data}}', {
            data: {
                user_email: user.email
            }
        },
        function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                ...
            } else if (result.length > 0) {
                ...
            } else {
                // this.connection is undefined ????????????
                this.connection.query('INSERT INTO users {{values values}}', {
                    values: {
                        user_name: user.username,
                        user_email: user.email,
                        user_password: user.password
                    }
                }),
                function (err, result) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.connection` is undefined because this.connection is on the instance of `playermodel` the callback function passed to the first query does not know about the context of the playermodel instance.

`user` should be defined though.  You can get around the `this.connection` being undefined by either binding the function or setting a reference to `this` in a variable the the callback will have access to.

```
//Bind
        playermodel.prototype = {

        registerByEmail: function (user, callback) {
            //check firts if the user already exists
            this.connection.query('SELECT user_id FROM users {{where data}}', {
                data: {
                    user_email: user.email
                }
            },
            function (err, result) {

                if (err) {
                    ...
                } else if (result.length > 0) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    // this.connection is undefined ????????????
                    this.connection.query('INSERT INTO users {{values values}}', {
                        values: {
                            user_name: user.username,
                            user_email: user.email,
                            user_password: user.password
                        }
                    }),
                    function (err, result) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            //HERE
            }.bind(this));
        }

    }

or

    //me reference to this
        playermodel.prototype = {

            registerByEmail: function (user, callback) {
                //HERE
                var me = this;
                //check firts if the user already exists
                this.connection.query('SELECT user_id FROM users {{where data}}', {
                    data: {
                        user_email: user.email
                    }
                },
                function (err, result) {

                    if (err) {
                        ...
                    } else if (result.length > 0) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        //HERE
                        me.connection.query('INSERT INTO users {{values values}}', {
                            values: {
                                user_name: user.username,
                                user_email: user.email,
                                user_password: user.password
                            }
                        }),
                        function (err, result) {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```